# Custom identity provider in Amazon Mobile Hub/ Amazon Web Services

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am new to Amazon Mobile Hub as a backend. Before this I was using Parse which essentially did everything for me. In Amazon Mobile Hub, for sign in, there is a custom sign in option. The info for this particular option on the amazon website is as follows:

'If you have an existing authentication process, you can use your own backend to authenticate your users. This involves interaction between your end user device, your backend for authentication, and Amazon Cognito. Learn more about authenticating your own users.'

I am really confused with this. So is there no option for creating a custom user database in amazon web services? If so, what kind of external services would I have to use (like Outh 0 or something). If so could anyone direct me to any seminar which explains about custom user database.

Can Amazon's Identity and Access Management help me in this? The documentation for this service only gives code in java and I am an ios developer so I am having problems in understanding this.

If anyone has ever used parse the I am looking for something like the users class in Parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vishisht,

For the custom identity provider, the Mobile Hub generated iOS Sample App does not have a fully documented solution yet. When creating the project in the Mobile Hub console and enabling “Custom” sign in, Mobile Hub is simply creating a “Developer provider name” associated with the default Cognito Identity Pool created for that project.

For Cognito Developer Authenticated Identities, you do need to create your own backend service to handle your end-user identities.Using developer authenticated identities involves interaction between the end-user device (a Mobile Hub generated sample app, perhaps), your backend for authentication, and Amazon Cognito.

The authentication server is a simple application designed to store user credentials in a secure manner and provides an OpenID Connect token to authenticated users. The authentication server can be built using AWS resources such as a web server running on an EC2 instance or an application running on an Elastic Beanstalk environment. The following blog is an end-to-end solution for building the backend authentication server and using the sample Cognito code from Github to directly interact with the backend server. Unfortunately, the sample authentication service IS only written in Java.

Integrating Amazon Cognito using developer authenticated identities: An end-to-end example:
https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en

Btw – I have used Parse and AWS or Mobile Hub does not have anything like the “Users” class. However, with Cognito Identity and Sync, you do have control over user profiles, allows multiple providers per user, and allows you to sync user profiles between devices. The Cognito Identity and Cognito Sync examples are integrated into the Mobile Hub generated sample apps through the “User Data Storage” feature.